# Mysql, pivot table working in sqlfiddle but not working in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, pivot, sqlfiddle

I had recently posted a question that was miraculously answered in regards to pivoting a mysql result.  Although it was solved and worked in the accompanied sqlfiddle, I can't seem to get the query working when I bring it back onto my database (in phpmyadmin).   I checked the versions, and the fiddle is version 5.1.61 and my MySql is 5.1.66-cll.  Any thoughts?  Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/59727/1   thank you in advnace for any help.

Comment: Have you tried placing the code in a stored procedure?

Comment: I have not. Not even sure how to create one. I get stuck on the In/Out  part.

Comment: @blufeet, I think my @sql is getting cutoff before it finsished compiling the full string, (see the lone "s" at the end) How can I declare it longer? Thank you
sum(case when disposition_codes.`name` = 'V' then 1 else 0 end) AS `V`,
sum(case when disposition_codes.`name` = 'VO' then 1 else 0 end) AS `VO`,
s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment and previous question about pivoting.  It sound like you need to increase the length of the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

The default length is 1024.

To change the length you will want to use the following before your code to generate the dynamic sql query:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

You can either change the `GLOBAL` or `SESSION` length and replace the `val` with the length that you need.

Comment: Holy Moly, that was great! I can't thank you enough Blufeet, thank you for seeing this answer all the way through!

Comment: @alex happy to help, I am glad we finally figured it out. :)